# create dialog that cannot be dismissed with ESC

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dialog that cannot be dismissed by pressing ESC. My use case is that I will be using this dialog to prompt the user to re-login upon trying to perform certain sensitive operations.

I have tried the following but it's not working: pressing `ESC` does dismiss the dialog and, moreover, the 'keyup' listener is not even entered:

```html
  <html>
  <body>
    <dialog id='dialog' >
      You shouldn't be able to dismiss me by pressing ESC - yet you can!
    </dialog>
    <script>
     var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
     dialog.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
       console.log('keyup '+e.keyCode);
       if (e.keyCode === 27) {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
       }
       });
     dialog.showModal();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the event listener to the Body.

Updated to handle deprecated [KeyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

```js
var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
var body = document.getElementById('body');

body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var handled = false;
  if (e.key !== undefined && e.key === 27) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.key and set handled true.
    handled=true;
  } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined && e.keyCode === 27) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyCode and set handled true.
    handled=true;
  }

  if (handled) {
    // Suppress "double action" if event handled
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});

dialog.showModal();
```

```html
<html>
  <body id='body'>
    <dialog id='dialog' >
      You shouldn't be able to dismiss me by pressing ESC - yet you can!
    </dialog>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the solution in the general case is to add the event listener on the **parent** of the dialog element?

Comment: [Per MDN and keycode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode): "This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."

Comment: Just to confirm this solution. Two things need to happen: (a) attach the event listener in body or document and (b) replace 'keyup' with 'keydown'. Either of them alone is not sufficient. Also instead of event.keyCode one might check event.code (but this is optional for the time being).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`dialog.addEventListener('keyup', ....)`

with

`document.addEventListener('keydown', ...)`

Comment: 'keydown' produces the exact same behaviour

Comment: all right, that's indeed correct advice. Two things need to happen: (a) attach the event listener in body or document and (b) replace 'keyup' with 'keydown'. Either of them alone is not sufficient

Comment: that's what the answer says ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the keyboard's input.
But the one issue is that it blocks all the keystrokes.
So you can do this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <dialog id='dialog' >
      You shouldn't be able to dismiss me by pressing ESC - yet you can!
    </dialog>
    <script>
     document.onkeydown = function(e) {
       return false;
     }
      dialog.showModal();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```